# Check array contain at least all value of array

Tags: mysql, join

I got a question about MySQL query.

I have a table `role` and another table `context`. Each role could be linked with multiple context using a join table `role_context`. Example:

```
roleA->context1
roleA->context2
roleB->context1
```

I want a query to get all Roles that match all context I give. Example:

- If I have `['context1']` in parameter I want `['roleA', 'roleB']` in result.
- If I have `['context2']` in parameter I want `['roleA']` in result.
- If I have `['context1', 'context2']` in parameter I want `['roleA']` in result.

I have tried to use

```
SELECT *
FROM role_context
INNER JOIN context ON role_context.context_name = context.name
WHERE context.name IN ["ETT","FR"]
```

But like it's an in it return `roleA` and `roleB` for my third condition.

Does someone have an idea for this query?
Or maybe my SQL architecture is not good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The architecture is OK, its just that SQL does not have built-in operators for such tasks. You can use the following query to select roles that have all contexts in the given list (must be passed as an `IN` clause):

```
SELECT role_context.role_name
FROM role_context
JOIN context ON role_context.context_name = context.name
WHERE context.name IN ('context1', 'context2')
GROUP BY role_context.role_name
HAVING COUNT(context.name) = 2 -- here 2 corresponds to the number of items in the above list
```